# website with horizontal scrolling, but separate pages

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, layout, horizontal-scrolling

I want to create a website with scrolling layout. Something like this:
[Example](http://www.queness.com/post/356/create-a-vertical-horizontal-and-diagonal-sliding-content-website-with-jquery)

But having all the content in a single html document, might make the page really heavy and also the url in address bar will not change for different pages.

But how can I have the website like horizontal but with different pages or at least different url in the address bar? Such as this example:
[example 2](http://carrotcreative.com/#!/)

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

The second example you posted still has all of the content in a single HTML document.  The only difference is the author has added some logic that appends a hash to the url when the page changes, and likely some javascript to check that hash on page load and pre-scroll to the designated page for persistence.

If you want to go a different route, and prevent all of the content from being included in your HTML document, you can use ajax to populate the "off-screen" content.

```
// when a link is clicked...
$.get('/page2', function(response){
    // load the content into an off-screen div
    $('.offscreen-div').html(response);

    // Use some jQuery to slide in the screen here
    my_slide_method($('.offscreen-div'));

    // Update the url hash
    window.location.hash = '!/page2';
});
```

This is pseudocode, but it should get you started.

Comment: Thank you for your respond.  I am not very good are JS and ajax.  I made a basic of my site: http://mersadesign.com/demo/scroll/
So can you explain it more and let me know what should I add, according to this basic layout.

Answer (score 0):

The second website you have as an example only has one page. It uses anchors to mark which page they're on. You can do this also by having JS read the page location when it starts and automatically move to that part of the page. This site that you have as example 2 also uses ajax to load the new pages as they are clicked on. I would avoid using this because it subtracts from the slide effect when the page loads after it slides.

Suggestions:

- Use jQuery for the animations
- Use anchors to mark the 'page' it's on for browser navigation uses
- Use ajax to load the other pages after the initial page loads (as Casey said)

Comment: Thank you for your respond.  As I explain in previous post, I am not good at ajax.
I want the website has pages, like: example.com/music.  Or similar like this with hash.  As I left the link in the previous post, can you explain how to have something like this? Thanks

Comment: @Dan - just remove return false from below the `$('#wrapper').scrollTo` line.